# hive sql query to merge columns

Tags: sql, hive

I have run both queries below on the same table with different filtering criterion:

```
hive> select * from mailing1 where layer ='db_gold';
OK
db_gold 400
db_gold 500
db_gold 600

hive> select * from mailing1 where layer ='db_insight';
OK
db_insight  100
db_insight  200
db_insight  300
```

I am trying to combine both queries and generate an output like:

```
db_gold 400 db_insight 100
db_gold 500 db_insight 200
db_gold 600 db_insight 300
```

I already tried to "union" both the tables as below, with no luck:

```
select * from mailing1 where layer ='db_insight' 
 union 
select * from mailing1 where layer ='db_gold';
db_gold         400
db_gold         500
db_gold         600
db_insight      100
db_insight      200
db_insight      300
```

Comment: `union` isn't supported in Hive. Use `union all` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `JOIN` operator is necessary, but there is no column for join. You can use row numbers of tables for this purpose:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT row_number() OVER () rn, * FROM mailing1 WHERE layer = 'db_insight') t1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT row_number() OVER () rn, * FROM mailing1 WHERE layer = 'db_gold') t2
ON t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

Comment: This solution is not safe, and I don't know if there's a way of making it safe with your table structure. The SQL standard does not ensure row order by default. This query may show the right result today, but if you insert/delete/update rows it may join the wrong rows. You need to specify an `ORDER BY` clause to make it safe.